# Add Tab Bar to Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add a tab bar with three options (Home) the first view, (Incidences) with the second view, and (Info) with the third view, in the first view I have 2 buttons that shows the second and the third view.

What I have to do to add tab bar with these 3 tabs, always visible in the App?

I have this structure now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New project -> Tabbed Application.
Replace the First and Second Views with your viewControllers. There will be no need for your left hand side view as the tabs will be your buttons

Comment: If you want a landing page with your introduction, add a 3rd tab with it. Leaving you with 3 tabs: Home, Incidences and Info

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I have now the three tabs navigating correctly by the three views. But I have two problems now. When I click in a button (button, not tab) of the first view (that shows other views), the tabs disappear, and the back button of the navigation controller does not appear neither.

Comment: The actions performed by your buttons are now done by your tabs. No need to have buttons and tabs both on screen and doing the same thing. It would be best if you remove the buttons and adapt your text to indicate something like "select the appropriate tab bellow"

Answer (score 1):

Each UIViewController in UITabBarController could be embedded in an UINavigationController at your convenience, that way you'll be able to use all of the features that you need.

Apple guideline for Tabbar: [Tab Bar Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW2)

Basically, you need to select the View Controller of (associated with) Tab Controller ▶ click on `Editor` menu item ▶ select `Embed in` and click on `Navigation Controller`

[image]

> For correct flow of navigation using tabbar you need to bind tabbar
>   controller with View Controller first and then embed navigation
>   controller to tabbar. Similar way you can also embed navigation
>   controller to tabbar controller, but its not the correct flow.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I have now the three tabs navigating correctly by the three views. But I have two problems now. When I click in a button (button, not tab) of the first view (that shows other views), the tabs disappear, and the back button of the navigation controller does not appear neither.

Comment: Pl. share your code/design here, so I can help you better